# Conditional formatting with date comparison in Google Sheets

Tags: excel, google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I'm rather stuck on what should be a simple formula for a couple of conditional formatting rules in Google Sheets. My data consists of dates in the format `DD/MM/YYYY` (as set in Format->Number->Date). I've got a reference date "Last Updated" at `A1`, and a column of dates at the range `B1:B9`. Both of my rules are applied to this range, and should work like the following:

1. IF **this** date is greater than or equal to (i.e. later) the date at A1 --> Background is yellow.
2. IF **this** date is less than (i.e. earlier) the date at A1 --> Background is green.

I've tried a number of different formulas, but none seem to work properly or as expected. For example, with the first conditional formatting rule:

- `=$B1 >= A1`
- `=GTE($B1, A1)`

...and again with `VALUE($B1)`, `DATEVALUE($B1)`

Here are the results of the first rule with a custom formula `=(VALUE($B1) >= VALUE(A1))`. It doesn't look too accurate to me.

```
-- A ---------- B ---------- Expected ---------- Actual ----------
1  02/02/2015   01/01/2015   FALSE               FALSE
2               02/01/2015   FALSE               TRUE (YELLOW)
3               03/01/2015   FALSE               TRUE (YELLOW)
4               01/02/2015   FALSE               TRUE (YELLOW)
5               02/02/2015   TRUE (YELLOW)       TRUE (YELLOW)
6               03/02/2015   TRUE (YELLOW)       FALSE
7               01/03/2015   TRUE (YELLOW)       FALSE
8               02/03/2015   TRUE (YELLOW)       FALSE
9               03/03/2015   TRUE (YELLOW)       TRUE (YELLOW)
```

I'm hoping that I'm just overlooking something simple, could someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: @pnuts Because this could apply to an excel formula as well (afaik the syntax is the same).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to set the dollar signs on A1. Otherwise as you copy the conditional formatting formula down, it will change to =$B2>=A2, etc., so you will be comparing B2 with an empty cell (or whatever happens to be in A2, A3 etc. in your sheet):-

```
=B1>=$A$1
```

Of course it doesn't do any harm to put the dollar sign in front of the B as well, but not necessary if you're just formatting one column.

[image]

Comment: I am now using a custom formula, however tried with between and dates, which both didn't work.  No idea why, seemed they were correct.

http://imgbox.com/LLwUyEL9

Comment: Looks like you'd have to put =today()  and =today()-60 if using between, but date is before should work with just today.

Answer (score -1):

A bit more detail...

[image]

I have a table with dates, and I want to strike out all of the dates that have passed based on the current date/time.  I used `= A22<now()` where `A22` is the upper left-hand cell in the table, and it worked as expected.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).